# UnboundLocalError at /contact/ ---Django 1.8

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

I keep getting the error
"local variable 'form_message' referenced before assignment" at this particular line:
"                       form_full_name,  "

Here is my code in django 1.8:

```
def contact(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form_full_name = form.cleaned_data.get("full_name")
        form_email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        form_message = form.cleaned_data.get("message")

        subject = 'Site contact form'
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_email = [from_email]

        contact_message = "%s: %s via %s"%(
            form_full_name, 
            form_message, 
            form_email)

        send_mail(subject,
            contact_message,
            from_email,
            to_email,
            fail_silently=False)        



    context = {
        "form": form,

    }

    return render(request, "forms.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code mixes tabs and spaces. Python expands tabs to *8 spaces*, not 4, but your editor and Stack Overflow do.

As such, your `if form.is_valid():` block *ends* at the `form_message = form.cleaned_data.get("message")` line, and the *remainder* of your function is **not** part of the `if` tests:

[image: source text with tabs as lines]

Each line in the indentation is a tab, I've set my editor to use 8 spaces for each tab so you can see how *Python* sees your function.

So, whenever `if form.is_valid():` is false, your `contact_message` line is still executed and `form_full_name` is not defined.

Have your text editor replace all tabs with 4 spaces, then configure your editor to expand tabs when used as indentation.